# How to put a final summary message in a yacc program?

Tags: c, yacc, lexical-analysis

When I redirect input to my yacc program from an input file, after it finishes parsing the file I want the yacc parser to print a summary of what it did.  I want it to do the same thing if I am entering input through the keyboard and then I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you want it in yacc/bison or (f)lex? You could just provide your own `main()` function that calls `yyparse()`, and then prints a message at the end.

Comment: I want it in yacc instead of flex.

Comment: The answer to this question should be obvious to anyone who has actually tried writing a program using yacc. I have noticed a pattern of asking questions by Phenom like this.

Answer (score 0):

on the grammar you can call a function
the function should be on the third part

```
FIRST PART

%%
second PART

GRAMMAR {  CALL YOUR FUNCTION();}
GRAMMAR2 VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 {CALL YOUR FUNCTION2($1,$2,$3);}

%%
third PART

YOUR FUNCTION(){}
YOUR FUNCTION2(int c, char*y , int z){}

 int main (void) {
}
    void yyerror (char *s) {fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);}
```

your function can print any thing you want also the grammar becouse you now from where it call the function by the parameter you give

Answer (score -4):

I found out that the solution to my problem is to create a function yywrap() in the .y file.  That function will run when yacc encounters an EOF, which is either the end of an  input file or the user pressing Ctrl-D.  This is the solution.

Comment: This runs when _lex_ encounters EOF, not when yacc does. These are two different times. It is an important distinction to make. `yywrap` shouldn't be doing anything anyway - it's a terrible form of "flow control" built into lex. The kind of actions you might do in `yywrap` should be handled in your program's `main()` function.

Comment: -1: agreeing with Chris, it's there so you can change to the next input file, when processing many files.

Comment: I don't have a main function, and even if I did, I doubt that it could do anything since main would be in the .l file and all my variables are in the .y file.

Comment: All (C/C++) programs have a `main()` function, you're just using the one provided for you by the yacc library.